coinbase script arbitrary data in coinbase input
01000000 .............................. Version    

01 .................................... Number of inputs     
| 00000000000000000000000000000000    
| 00000000000000000000000000000000 ...  Previous outpoint TXID     
| ffffffff ............................ Previous outpoint index     
|    
| 29 .................................. Bytes in coinbase    
| |     
| | 03 ................................ Bytes in height    
| | | 4e0105 .......................... Height: 328014    
| |    
| | 062f503253482f0472d35454085fffed    
| | f2400000f90f54696d65202620486561    
| | 6c74682021 ........................ Arbitrary data      
| 00000000 ............................ Sequence     

01 .................................... Output count   
| 2c37449500000000 .................... Satoshis (25.04275756 BTC)   
| 1976a914a09be8040cbf399926aeb1f4    
| 70c37d1341f3b46588ac ................ P2PKH script   
| 00000000 ............................ Locktime    

when building the coinbase transaction Arbitrary data is the coinbase script? can you make it whatever you want? :$

BIP 34 requires the script to start with a push of block height.
The script length cannot exceed a limit ( ~100 bytes IIRC)

In the coinbase transaction, the arbitrary data in the coinbase script can indeed be customized, but it’s not just a free-for-all. Miners typically use this space for things like including the mining pool name, extra nonce, or even creative messages. However, it’s essential to ensure that the data inserted doesn't interfere with the transaction’s proper function, as it’s still part of the validated script. Keep it fun, but keep it functional! 
